# DropDown Menu not floating to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu that i need to start from the very left of the webpage and width should be 100% to the last of the webpage but i am not bale to do it.Also i want to remove the last empty column in the menu bar but not able to figure remove it..

Here is the HTML...

```
<ul id="dropdown_nav">

    <li><a class="first" href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop #4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Artciles</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Announcements #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Announcements #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Announcements #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Announcements #4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Freebies</a></li>

    <li><a class="last" href="#">Other Stuff</a>
        <ul class="sub_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Stuff #4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And this is the fiddle link..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PSpR/)

Please help me..

Comment: we cant open fiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9PSpR/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```